# Play Media from DB Android

Tags: android, audio

My app will give a sound when the user opens some page. For example, I have 50 pages, therefore I keep 50 sound files in my raw folder. A database stores the associations between the page number and the sound to be played for it:

```
==================
 page | sound
------+-----------
 1    | android
 2    | star
 3    | bluewater
 …    | …
```

So how to call that sound and play it? I know how to call sound if just one sound example:

```
MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.splashsound);
```

but i confuse how to call sound, name file from db and play it from raw resource.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read data from database using Cursor then you can get path for audio file you want to play so just pass it to MediaPlayer.

If you want to know how to fetch recoeds from database [here is tutorial link..](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) this link shows you how to use database as well as ContentProvider.

Hope this explanation works for you..

Comment: i know how to get data from database. but the problem i dont know how to make R.raw.[data from database]

Comment: you can try to set setDataSource() method of Media player..

mediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);

Comment: can u give me simple example? i still confuse to make a path from raw folder

Comment: you stored path but where your files are actually located is in SDcard.??

Comment: nope my sound inside res/raw/[filenamesound], but i save filenamesound in database. so i can know which sound will be play in each page

Comment: You can try this File sourceFile=new File(context.getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+"/pathOfFileFromDB"); or pass just filename may works

Comment: pathOfFil‌​eFromDB --> is this name of my db?

Comment: i still dont understand about that

Comment: I can only give you this link of MediaPlayer class onCreate() [Link..](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create(android.content.Context, android.net.Uri))
First read above provided method carefully in documentation you find your way of doing it (and check what exactly your storing in data as path of media file, try to play it by hardcoding it)
Hope this helps you..